# Semicolon and period in software instructions

Tags: technical-writing, word-choice, punctuation, sentence-structure

I'm writing a software manual and I worry about my semicolon usage. I believe I'm using them correctly, but it's not that I have to.

My project is a software manual.

People scan for the information they want, looking for keywords or specific phrases, rather than read every single sentence.

The feedback, in the form of edits from co-workers and test-readers are adding words to the text, making it sound like a class paper. I think the language should be minimalist. They also keep trying to change the text to 3rd person, but that's another story. In short, I am unclear whether they or I need to lighten up some.

## TLDR

Which do you like better?

- Enter your User ID; click OK.

  - I like this one because it still conveys the closeness of the subsequent action. It seems to flow more to me than a complete break into two sentences.
- Enter your User ID. Click OK.

  - This works for me, I'd prefer it to having to add the word "and". However, it seems more stiff and formal to me.
- Enter your User ID and click OK.

  - I object to this because of the extra words. I think the punctuation does what "and" does with half the space.

*I'm looking for opinions*.

I know there are lots of things that will work, as many have stated. I want to hear your thoughts, like @Murphy L. 's comment.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/style-guide/punctuation/semicolons seems to agree.

Comment: Personally, I like the first one, with the semicolon.

Comment: *My co-workers and people I talk with don't seem to understand how minimalist I think it should be.*  Any document written by a committee will be more akin to a camel than to the horse you set out to write.  Write it, write it well (you show every sign of having a clear idea of how to do that), and send it to press.

Comment: Moved to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585813/semicolon-period-and-and-in-software-instructions

Comment: No, nothing has been moved. You copied the question  to a different site wothout explaining. Then a user called you out.

Comment: So what would you do?

Comment: I mean there are two votes to close, you are welcome to join them.

Comment: It's more likely to be closed on EL&U, only three votes are needed and there are already two. What would I do? I would have said in the duplicate question that you are looking for a more technical answer which is missing on Writing.SE. It is *possible* to have two identical questions on two different sites, if the question is on-topic and has never been asked before.

Comment: @PierceDevol you say "I'm looking for opinions." The default on every Stack Exchange site is for *questions inviting opinions to be closed*. SE is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. You might like to re-read [ask]. :-)

Comment: This site is not suitable for opinions. All questions must have an authoritative answer. Please refer to [our help](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for an idea what to avoid in asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

Which you chose is immaterial.  Of your samples, none are wrong.

When creating a technical documentation project should include a style guide. It can be one your company made up or it can be one of the many style guides out there for documentation. The web can provide you with [links](https://www.writethedocs.org/guide/writing/style-guides/) from a dizzying array of options, from [Microsoft Style Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/style-guide/welcome/) to [Google's Style Guide](https://developers.google.com/style), and most will be free of charge.

You can find for fee User-Manual style guides and development tools, but they are mostly following one of the free style guides.

There are only two criteria that are important: readability/clarity and maintainability.  And, for the ADA gotcha-people out there I consider accessibility to be part of readability/clarity.

Comment: @PierceDevol Further to EDL's wholly correct Answer, I suggest you look again first at the Title of this Question, and then at the wording of your exposition… neither being standard English. Also, you left out "Enter your User ID then click OK" which of course isn't mandatory, but equally clearly was a choice as obvious as the other three…

Comment: Personally, I'm more looking for a gut feeling in my answers. I understand all of those options. So far the best thing closest to an answer I was looking is @'Murphy L.' I really just want to hear opinions.

Comment: Maybe I'm misusing Stack, I guess I was looking for opinions but the edits seemed to have removed all that stuff.

Comment: @PierceDevol, this site endeavors to avoid opinion questions.  Try reddit or fb if you are looking for validation

Comment: Reddit sounds like a fine idea. I think it is harsh to call a minor attempt at reader research   a search for validation. I even admitted that I might not be using the site right. I'll close the question, thanks for the attitude.

Comment: @PierceDevol Just to put it out there, "validation" is also a valid technical term for, basically, getting user/reader opinions on your work so far, to see if it has value for them. We do that constantly in agile development. (Or, are supposed to.) I know the word also has negative connotations in common usage, but I'd opt for the more positive interpretation while it's an option.

Comment: I think the facebook part before it triggered me.